# What does the 'At sign' mean in yaml config for azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

In Azure devops pipeline there are at signs with a number after the task names. I figured these would be like version numbers. But is this the case, and what is the difference between using:

`- task: CopyFiles@1`

and

`- task: CopyFiles@2`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What does the 'At sign' mean in yaml config for azure pipeline

Yes, it represents the task version. More precisely, the **major** version.

According the document [Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> In YAML, you specify the **major version using @ in the task name**. For
>   example, to pin to version 2 of the task

Besides,

> what is the difference between `CopyFiles@1` and `CopyFiles@2`

I am afraid no one can completely list the exact difference between the two versions task. This is a general iterative process of software development. When we release the initial version, we will continue to repeat our products based on user feedback. When we decide to add a major version, we will release the next major version. This is the origin of `V2`.

And from [the history of CopyFilesV2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/commits/master/Tasks/CopyFilesV2), we could to know the know the iterations and differences between different Minor or Patch versions.

So, the difference between `CopyFiles@1` and `CopyFiles@2` should be the fixes of multiple issues and the improvement of functionality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so what does ...@0 in yaml stand for?

Answer (score 3):

these are indeed version numbers. usually there are some changes between task behaviour\capabilities between different versions. task syntax might remain intact (although its not always the case).

I dont know what is the difference in this particular case, but given this is a copy files task, there probably is none.